# Save a Bert model with custom forward function and heads on Hugginface

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I have created my own BertClassifier model, starting from a pretrained and then added my own classification heads composed by different layers. After the fine-tuning, I want to save the model using model.save_pretrained() but when I print it upload it from pretrained i don't see my classifier head.
The code is the following. How can I save the all structure on my model and make it full accessible with  `AutoModel.from_preatrained('folder_path')` ?
. Thanks!

```
class BertClassifier(PreTrainedModel):
    """Bert Model for Classification Tasks."""
    config_class = AutoConfig
    def __init__(self,config, freeze_bert=True): #tuning only the head
        """
         @param    bert: a BertModel object
         @param    classifier: a torch.nn.Module classifier
         @param    freeze_bert (bool): Set `False` to fine-tune the BERT model
        """
        #super(BertClassifier, self).__init__()
        super().__init__(config)

        # Instantiate BERT model
        # Specify hidden size of BERT, hidden size of our classifier, and number of labels
        self.D_in = 1024 #hidden size of Bert
        self.H = 512
        self.D_out = 2
 
        # Instantiate the classifier head with some one-layer feed-forward classifier
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.D_in, 512),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(512, self.D_out),
            nn.Tanh()
        )
 


    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):


         # Feed input to BERT
        outputs = self.bert(input_ids=input_ids,
                             attention_mask=attention_mask)
         
         # Extract the last hidden state of the token `[CLS]` for classification task
        last_hidden_state_cls = outputs[0][:, 0, :]
 
         # Feed input to classifier to compute logits
        logits = self.classifier(last_hidden_state_cls)
 
        return logits
```

```
configuration=AutoConfig.from_pretrained('Rostlab/prot_bert_bfd')
model = BertClassifier(config=configuration,freeze_bert=False)
```

Saving the model after fine-tuning

```
model.save_pretrained('path')
```

Loading the fine-tuned model

```
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('path')
```

Printing the model after loading shows I have as the last layer the following and missing my 2 linear layer:

```
 (output): BertOutput(
          (dense): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
          (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
          (dropout): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (adapters): ModuleDict()
          (adapter_fusion_layer): ModuleDict()
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (pooler): BertPooler(
    (dense): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
    (activation): Tanh()
  )
  (prefix_tuning): PrefixTuningPool(
    (prefix_tunings): ModuleDict()
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something is wrong with the `config_class` attribute inside your `BertClassifier` class. According to the documentation you need to create an additional config class which inherits form `PretrainedConfig` and initialises the `model_type` attribute with the name of your custom model.

The `BertClassifier's config_class` has to be consistent with your custom config class type.
Afterwards you can register your config and model with the following calls:

```
AutoConfig.register('CustomModelName', CustomModelConfigClass)
AutoModel.register(CustomModelConfigClass, CustomModelClass)
```

And load your finetuned model with `AutoModel.from_pretrained('YourCustomModelName')`

An incomplete example based on your code could look like this:

```
class BertClassifierConfig(PretrainedConfig):
    model_type="BertClassifier"


class BertClassifier(PreTrainedModel):
    config_class = BertClassifierConfig
    # ...


configuration = BertClassifierConfig()
bert_classifier = BertClassifier(configuration)

# do your finetuning and save your custom model
bert_classifier.save_pretrained("CustomModels/BertClassifier")

# register your config and your model
AutoConfig.register("BertClassifier", BertClassifierConfig)
AutoModel.register(BertClassifierConfig, BertClassifier)

# load your model with AutoModel
bert_classifier_model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("CustomModels/BertClassifier")
```

Printing the model output should be similiar to this:

```
    (pooler): BertPooler(
      (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (activation): Tanh()
    )
  )
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512, bias=True)
    (1): Tanh()
    (2): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2, bias=True)
    (3): Tanh()
    (4): Linear(in_features=2, out_features=512, bias=True)
    (5): Tanh()
  )
```

Hope this helps.

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/custom_models#registering-a-model-with-custom-code-to-the-auto-classes

Comment: Hi @rbi
Do I need to initialize `bert_classifier = BertClassifier(configuration)` on loading `bert_classifier_model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("CustomModels/BertClassifier")`

I trained the custom model and saved it. But on loading the model using `AutoModel.from_pretrained("path")` I am getting key error.