# Modifying last layer of a pre-trained sentiment classification model to get a linear output

Tags: huggingface-transformers, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model

How can I modify a pre-trained sentiment classification model (e.g., 'bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment') to output a value between 0 and 1 instead of a classification tensor? The output should result in a number between 0 and 1, for example: 0.4. I would like to use an activation function like sigmoid to achieve this. Could you provide an example code snippet or guidance on how to make this modification?

I tried to get into the model definition, but I am unsure whether it is the only or the more complex way to solve that issue. As you can see here is the line (line 724) from the model definition from [github](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py).

```
class BertPreTrainingHeads(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.predictions = BertLMPredictionHead(config)
        self.seq_relationship = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to get into the model definition, you simply have to write your own `forward` method while also adding a `nn.Sigmoid` layer to the model initialization method.

```py
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoConfig
import torch.nn as nn

class CustomBERTModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model_name):
        super(CustomBERTModel, self).__init__()
        self.config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_name)
        self.bert = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name, config=self.config)
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.config.hidden_size, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )
        
    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):

        outputs = self.bert(
            input_ids=input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask
        )
        
        # we only want to get the hidden states of the [CLS] token
        pooled_output = outputs.pooler_output
        
        # pass it through the custom classifier
        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)
        
        return logits
```

This code works as expected and outputs a value between 0 and 1 instead of a classification tensor.

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased')

text = "I am very happy today!"
tokens = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt', padding='max_length', max_length=128)

model = CustomBERTModel('bert-base-multilingual-uncased')

input_ids = tokens['input_ids']
attention_mask = tokens['attention_mask']

logits = model(input_ids, attention_mask)
print(logits)
# tensor([[0.5064]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)
```

[Read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72503309/save-a-bert-model-with-custom-forward-function-and-heads-on-hugginface) for information on how to properly save and load this custom model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AutoModelForSequenceClassification`

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
 
model_name = 'bert-base-multilingual-uncased'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

For BERT, the `AutoModelForSequenceClassification` should have made use of the `[CLS]` object to predict the labels for your task. It starts learning to predict your labels in place of `[CLS]` and the output would be put into a sigmoid activation to give an logit output between `[0,1]` that will give you similar effects to the linear layer + activation.

To fine-tune the model to do sentiment / classification, take a look at https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/transformers_doc/training.ipynb

---

After fine-tuing, you can do something like this to use the model for inference/evaluation:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import pipeline
 

model_name = 'bert-base-multilingual-uncased'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)


classifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
classifier(["this is such a happy sentence", "this is a sad one"])
```

[out]:

```
[{'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.544954240322113},
 {'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.5412613749504089}]
```

**Note:** The `bert-base-multilingual-uncased` model doesn't do sentiment analysis out of the box, so it's advisable to fine-tune it on your data.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [torch.nn.Softmax](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softmax.html):

> Applies the Softmax function to an n-dimensional input Tensor
> rescaling them so that the elements of the n-dimensional output Tensor
> lie in the range [0,1] and sum to 1.

once you get `output=model(**kwargs)`:

```
probs=torch.nn.functional.softmax(output[0],dim=-1)
```

`dim=-1` is used in the softmax function to specify that the softmax operation should be applied along the last dimension of the input tensor, which is often used for probability distribution computations in classification tasks.